# C Array with memory problems in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

My C array of boolean values are not keeping their values the second time I run the Cocos2d Scene that has the array. The first time the app launches, the c array works fine and responds as expected, however after the scene is deallocated and then re-run the c array doesn't keep the values that are assigned to it. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the code below?

```
//.h
@interface GameplayLayer : CCLayer {
  bool playerLog[4];
  Hero *hero;
}

//.m
@implementation 
- (void)ccKeyDown:(NSEvent*)keyDownEvent{
    // Get pressed key (code)
    UInt16 keyCode = [keyDownEvent keyCode];
    // Set pressed key to true
    if (keyCode == 123) playerLog[0] = TRUE; // Left
    if (keyCode == 124) playerLog[1] = TRUE;  // Right
    if (keyCode == 126) playerLog[2] = TRUE;  // up
    if (keyCode == 125) playerLog[3] = TRUE;  // down
    // Other keys
    if (keyCode == 27) { } // Escape
}

 - (void)ccKeyUp:(NSEvent*)keyUpEvent
 {
     UInt16 keyCode = [keyUpEvent keyCode];
     // Set pressed key to true
     if (keyCode == 123) playerLog[0] = FALSE; // Left
     if (keyCode == 124) playerLog[1] = FALSE;  // Right
     if (keyCode == 126) playerLog[2] = FALSE;  // up
     if (keyCode == 125) playerLog[3] = FALSE;  // down
     // Other keys
    if (keyCode == 27) { } // Escape
}

-(void)update:(ccTime)delta {
  if (playerLog[0] == TRUE) {//false on the second run when key is pushed down}
```

Comment: `scene is deallocated` Is it possible this object is destroyed at that time?

Comment: @KarthikT Possibly, but how is it then being initialized the first time? Also how do I initialize the array?

Comment: I am really that aware of objective C to answer, maybe it is getting initialized to 0 by constructor?

Comment: @KarthikT I just tried declaring the bool as "bool* playerLog;" and then initializing it as "playerLog = calloc(4, sizeof(bool));" and then free it like "free(playerLog);" and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C-Array not adding objects in Cocos2d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883531/c-array-not-adding-objects-in-cocos2d)

Comment: please dont re-post questions. if you get no answer improve the first question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what the reason here is: you should not keep game state in a view-related class, in this case CCLayer.

You should have a place where you group game state together, see my writeup on shared instances here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/05/the-death-of-global-variables/

Comment: I have a singleton class called GameManager that is in control of the running and replacing of my scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I see no init method, you should create an init method to initialize your
ivars (especially `playerLog[]`) and/or make them properties.

```
-(id)init
{
   if (self = [super init])
   {
     playerLog[0]=playerLog[1]=playerLog[2]=playerLog[3]=0;
     hero=nil; // or allocate it, not clear from your ex. how u use that.
   }
   return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to either convert your `bool playerLog[4]` to NSMutableArray and use or you can try from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709844/dynamic-allocation-in-objective-c-returning-pointers)

Comment: 2-3 days I saw your same question, I asked you manually calloc, malloc and free the memory, but few people downvoted my answer. You can still try by either method as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I saw your post but didn't know where it went because I didn't know that people downvoted it. I tried the calloc and malloc method and yet it still didn't work. Also I tried converting into a NSMutableArray and it still isn't keeping the values.

Comment: Then just try by string it in NSArray

Comment: Turns out my issue was in the way I was deallocating my scene. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So finally you have did it... congrats:)